# How to reverse a function

Tags: jquery

Working on a point system that assigns points for every element with matching content in a group of search results. It works well when I compare the contents from `.per-results` to `.myself`, but it doesn't work when I do the comparison from .myself to .per-result.

When reversed, it still assigns points but it assigns the same amount of points for all `.per-result` when it should differ.

```js
$(function() {
      $('.per-result').each(function() {
        var $matches = $('span', this).filter(function() { // Each item
            var texts = $(this).text();
            return $('.myself span').filter(function() { // Are there matches in .three?
                return $(this).text() === texts;
            }).length > 0;
        }).length;
        $('.theyRate', this).text(('They score me ' + $matches * 6 + ' Points' ));
    });
  
  
  
  //Reversing the point system
  
        var $matches = $('.myself span', this).filter(function() { // Each item
            var texts = $(this).text();
            return $('.per-result span').filter(function() { // Are there matches in .three?
                return $(this).text() === texts;
            }).length > 0;
        }).length;
        $('.iRate').text(('I score them ' + $matches * 6 + ' Points' ));

  
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-family: calibri;
}

div span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.theyRate {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #444;
}

.iRate {
  color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="per-result">
<h2>Result 1</h2>

<span>Utmost inportant</span>
<span>Utmost inportant</span>

<span>Slightly inportant</span>
<span>Slightly inportant</span>
<span>Slightly inportant</span>
    <span class="theyRate"></span>
      <span class="iRate"></span>
  </div>


<div class="per-result">
<h2>Result 2</h2>
<span>Utmost inportant</span>
<span>Utmost inportant</span>
<span>Utmost inportant</span>

<span>Slightly inportant</span>


 <span class="theyRate"></span>
      <span class="iRate"></span>
</div>


<div class="per-result">
<h2>Result 3</h2>
<span>Utmost inportant</span>


<span>Slightly inportant</span>

 <span class="theyRate"></span>
      <span class="iRate"></span>


</div>





<div class="myself">
<h1>Searchman</h1>
<span>Utmost inportant</span>
<span>Utmost inportant</span>
<span>Utmost inportant</span>

<span>Slightly inportant</span>
<span>Slightly inportant</span>
<span>Slightly inportant</span>

</div>
```

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrg21nq6/)

Comment: I noticed you are missing a closing div on the first <div class="per-result">. That is throwing off the results (102 -> 30). Not sure if that is the answer to your question, but adding it in changes the scores.

Comment: No, that isn't the answer. Missing tag was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are always getting the same answer for iRate is because the 'reversed' code loops through each of the 'myself' spans and checks if there are any matches in all the 'per-result' spans. It is not limited to one 'per-result' section at a time like the first function. Also, it only needs to find one match in the entire result set to be a match. So all six of the 'myself' spans will always be counted as a point.

```
return $('.per-result span').filter(function()
```

Also, you are updating all three of the $('.iRate').text all at once with one call.

```
$('.iRate').text(('I score them ' + $matches * 6 + ' Points' ));
```

Ideally you would update the iRate for each section individually.